# How does Kotlin generates bindings for the JVM automatically?

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm

I'm interested in the subject of language interop.

For the Kotlin/JVM target we're able to call Java code directly without having to define any binding interfaces or using tools such as the [SWIG library](http://www.swig.org/), JNI and others. How was that achieved ?

Comment: Because Kotlin/JVM is compiled to Java bytecode. You can see that the compilation results in .class files. In fact you can decompile Kotlin to Java code using standard Java decompilers. Same happens with other languages that target the JVM like Scala, Clojure, etc...

Comment: Thnak you for your reply, but this just replies the "why" of the question as in "Why is it possible", I'm interested in implementation

Comment: What do you mean by "implementation"? Java bytecode is same as any other final resulting machine code for Kotlin/Native or JavaScript for Kotlin/JS. After building the AST it is just a matter of implementing the architecture's machine code you want to output. For implementation details [you can check the source code of the Kotlin compiler](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: the Java runtime handles it all; no bindings are needed.

All classes and interfaces that the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) runs (except for native calls using [JNI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) or similar) are provided to it as [Java bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) (typically in the form of .class files); it's the same whether that bytecode was compiled from Java, or Kotlin, or Groovy, or Scala, or any other JVM language.

The bytecode contains details of all the constructors, fields, and methods of a class or interface.  When that refers to other classes, it does so via their fully-qualified names (e.g. `java.lang.String`) — and the JVM knows how to find (e.g. by searching the classpath) and load any class given its fully-qualified name.  (Specifically, it uses a [ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) — usually the [system](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader--) one, though custom ones can be used where appropriate.)  Having loaded the class, instances can be constructed and their methods called directly.

So the JVM doesn't need any secondary means of identifying or accessing classes/interfaces or their methods; it's all specified in the bytecode and accessible directly.

(If you want more details, the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html) is probably the ultimate reference.)